# How to populate with options an angular ui-select after a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-promise, ui-select

I have the html

```
 <ui-select multiple ng-model="item.selectedOrganizations" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled" sortable="true" close-on-select="false">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select organizations...">{{$item.Name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="organization.Name as organization in organizationsDB | propsFilter: {Name: $select.search}">
                <div ng-bind-html="organization.Name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
 </ui-select>
```

I already have something in item.selectedOrganizations so I will prepopulate the select box with some values. An array of names.

```
item.selectedOrganizations = selectedOrganizations;
```

I will populate the options of the select box with some data.

```
$http.get('/admin/organizations')
    .success(function(data){
        vm.organizationsDB = data.data;
});
```

Everything works for now but of course I have to declare the variables:

```
 vm.organization = {};
 // vm.organizationsDB = [];
```

If I will leave the comment the select box will work but with errors in the console. If I remove the comment and declare first the organizationsDB variable there will be no errors in the syntax but the item.selectedOrganizations will not be prepopulated with the array of names.

Can anybody help me in this matter?

Answer (score 1):

Your view is slightly wrong, I guess you copied from an example and didn't quite tie it together with your own implementation.

I *think* that I have addressed your problem below (fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qmf49qo3/). I've added a spoof object literal in place of your promise response.

**View**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <ui-select tagging ng-model="vm.selectedOrganizations" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick one...">{{$select.selected.value}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="val as organization in vm.organizationsDB  | filter: $select.search track by organization.value">
      <div ng-bind="organization.value | highlight: $organization.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>

  </ui-select>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.select']);

app.controller("myCtrl", function() {
  vm = this;
  vm.isLoaded = false;
  vm.organizationsDB = [{
    'key': 1,
    'value': 'IBM'
  }, {
    'key': 2,
    'value': 'Microsoft'
  }];
  vm.selected;
  vm.selectedOrganizations = {
           'key': 1,
           'value': 'Prepopulated Value'
           }
});
```

Comment: I understand your point. But the ng-model is item.selectedOrganizations (which means I have multiple items). And I don't want to create it vm.selectedOrganizations = empty. I have already some values there.